# How to check duplicate and update item in listbox at a specific index

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have a listbox in which my selected items are added with their names and prices. Now i want to check if my selected item is in the listbox, if yes, then replace it's price and double it.

I'm able to check duplications but not able to update price.

```
    private void ProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button ProductButton = sender as Button;
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(ProductButton.Tag);

        Details details = dataAccess.ReadProductDetails(ProductID);

        decimal price = details.Price;

            if (CheckProductInListBox(details.Name))
            {
                 // what to do ?


            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString());
}

    }


private bool CheckProductInListBox(string name)
        {
            foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Contains(name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: It is always lovely to mix together presentation with the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your function to find and return the existing item (where appropriate, empty string if the item isn't found) you can then work backwards from there.

Assuming the item's name and added padding will always be the same, you can simple remove it from the existing item and be left with the string value of the price. This can easily be parsed to a decimal value, the price can then be added to the existing total to produce the new total.

Then, using this new total and same name as before, you simply replace the item currently at that index with the updated string.

Please do note, that this is not the cleanest and most elegant solution, as that would require reworking your whole approach to how UI elements and data interact.

```
private void ProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button ProductButton = sender as Button;
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
            int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(ProductButton.Tag);

            Details details = dataAccess.ReadProductDetails(ProductID);

            decimal price = details.Price;

            string foundItem = CheckProductInListBox(details.Name);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundItem))
            {
                string currentPriceString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(30), "");
                decimal currentPriceValue;

                if (Decimal.TryParse(currentPriceString, out currentPriceValue))
                {
                    currentPriceValue += price;
                    string newItem = details.Name.PadRight(30) + currentPriceValue.ToString();

                    int index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(foundItem);
                    listBox1.Items[index] = newItem;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Throw error
                }

            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString());
            }
        }


        private string CheckProductInListBox(string name)
        {
            foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Contains(name))
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: finally after several hours, this worked. Thanks a lot